# OpenCV: Draw HoughCircles accumulator value?

Tags: opencv, draw, accumulator

I want to draw the accumulator value  "accum" in  default funtion for opencv icvHoughCirclesGradient?
how can show it 
the link for function :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dlp914m9xnde603/icvHoughCirclesGradient.txt?dl=0

also you can find icvHoughCirclesGradient in opencv paths
opencv\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp

please any one help me 
Thanks

Comment: noone will sift through your dropbox. please paste the relevant and minimal part here.

Comment: Sorry for that. I want to show accum image for function icvHoughCirclesGradient that found in opencv paths

Comment: opencv\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp

Comment: even then,  a link to the [github src](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L795) will be more appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can show the result of accumulator after run opencv houghcircles function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715788/how-can-show-the-result-of-accumulator-after-run-opencv-houghcircles-function)